# How to get the "value" of a kernel density estimate in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm working with the KernelDensityEstimate package (https://github.com/JuliaRobotics/KernelDensityEstimate.jl) in Julia, which seems to work quite simply in terms of how an estimate is created. I'm aware of how to create the estimate (using the `kde!` function on a vector or matrix returns an object of class `BallTreeDensity`) and sample randomly from it, but I would like to get the "value" of the KDE at any point (i.e., as if it were a probability density function). I've searched the docs and haven't found much, so I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The `BallTreeDensity` is callable, you once you have

```
julia> using KernelDensityEstimate
julia> p100
BallTreeDensity:
  dims: 1
  Npts: 100
  bws:  [0.804591]
```

you can call

```
p100(points)
```

to obtain values at such points, e.g.

```
julia> p100([1.])
1-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.09056070794525749

julia> p100([1., 2.])
2-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.09056070794525749
 0.0449586510008976
```

You can see examples in the repo.
https://github.com/JuliaRobotics/KernelDensityEstimate.jl/blob/master/examples/EvaluatingDensities.jl

The structure accepts only `Vector{Float64}` as a parameter, so you have to pass it as vector of floats, it does not accept scalar argument or integer.